# How to get facebook fanpage's fans count for the given period?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I want to get facebook fanpage's number of fans for last 30 days. I can get current fans count calling Facebook Graph API `http://graph.facebook.com/id` where I get value of "likes" object from response JSON.
But, how can I get fans count for each day of last month? I need array of data.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get an access token for your page, and request the `manage_pages` permission.
Once you have this you will be able to query `http://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/insights` - all the statistical information you need can be retrieved from this endpoint.

Comment: Can I use this for those fanpages that are not mine? For example for rihanna fanpage?

Comment: No, insights is only available for objects you own

Comment: you cant get any information on other peoples pages or profiles that  they have not made public.
It is impossible (at this stage) to get that information for a page that is not owned (or managed) by you. - just like @Igy said...

Comment: But, how did they did that: http://www.famecount.com/facebook/coldplay They have graph for some period??

Comment: You can get some basic information such as likes and talking about this from the graph api
http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola
They collect data daily to create the graph